# CoffeeScript: iterate from the second element

Tags: coffeescript

How to start iteration from the second element with this comprehension:

```
destroy c for c, i in container.children
```

Cannot find an explanation of that in [docs](http://coffeescript.org/#loops)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't start from an arbitrary place in a comprehension.

Instead, add a `when` condition that simply checks whether the index of the iteration is greater than the first element.

```
destroy c for c, i in container.children when i >= 1
```

Comment: Is there any other way I can iterate through the array from an arbitrary place with CoffeeScript?

Comment: @ViktorDanilov `for i in [1..container.children.length]` is about it. What is wrong with the `when i >= ` solution?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. I just wanted to reseacrh is there a way to iterate the array from the second element without one extra calculation in the end, using CoffeeScript.